# exclude custom post type by meta key in wp_query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, meta-query, exclude

I'm trying to display a custom post type (properties) and exclude posts that have a certain meta value (sold). Is there a way that I can do this? I have this for my code so far:

```
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type'      => 'property',
                            'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
                            'meta_key'       => 'random_775',
                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                            'posts_per_page' => 100,
                        );

                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
                    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

So right now it shows all the custom post types even the ones that are 'sold'. How can I show the ones that are not sold? Also, sold is just a checkbox so it would have to know whether it was checked or not.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't use any other meta data, just add the following to your `$args`:

```
'meta_key' => 'sold',
'meta_value' => true, // or whatever it is you're using here
'meta_compare' => '!=',
```

Otherwise, use a `WP_Meta_Query`:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'sold',
        'value' => true,  // or whatever it is you're using here
        'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
    ),
),
```

See here for more information:

- [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)
- [`WP_Meta_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

Comment: Thanks, that worked but I no longer have the posts in alphabetical order. Meta_key -> 'random_775' was what was doing it but now that I have two meta_keys, it broke. Any suggestion on how to keep the order?

Comment: Hm, that's why I wrote the second part using a `WP_Meta_Query`. So this doesn't work either? Keep the `meta_key` and `orderby` parameters from your original code, and add the `meta_query`. If this is **not** working, I will post another solution (which uses standard sorting of PHP).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have another question where I'm using pre_get_posts but I still am having issues. [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115851/cant-sort-order-of-wp-query-with-2-meta-keys/115853?noredirect=1#comment163082_115853</)